# Displaying 0 instead of None in Web2py app

Tags: python, session, web2py

As mentioned in the title, I want to display `0` instead of `None` for the `session.counter` or `session.wrong_counter` in my Web2py app. I have tried about 10 different ways to do this but I am not getting it right for some reason.

This is the `Controller` for the page `score`:

```
def score():
    image = db.pic(request.args(0,cast=int)) or redirect(URL('index'))
    correct = image.id == session.pic_id
    next_game = random.randint(1, 35)
    wrong_counter = []
    right_counter = []
    if correct:
        session.counter = (session.counter or 0)+1
        right_counter=session.counter
    if not correct:
        session.wrong_counter = (session.wrong_counter or 0)+1
        wrong_counter=session.wrong_counter
    return locals()
```

In the `View` I have `{{=session.counter}}` and `{{=session.wrong_counter}}`. When the page `score` first visited during the `session` one of them will display `1` and the other will display `None` depending on the `correct` or `not correct` conditions as expected, however, I want to display `0` instead of `None`.

I would very much appreciate some advise.

Answer (score 0):

Simply initialize the `wrong_counter` value to 0 when `correct` is true, and wrong_counter is not set:

```
if correct:
    session.counter = (session.counter or 0)+1
    right_counter=session.counter
    if not session.wrong_counter:
       # This is the first time we have a correct answer
       wrong_counter = 0
    else:
       wrong_counter = (session.wrong_counter or 0)+1
    session.wrong_counter = wrong_counter
if not correct:
    session.wrong_counter = (session.wrong_counter or 0)+1
    wrong_counter=session.wrong_counter
```

That way, instead of having `None` as the default value, it will have 0.

However, you have set `right_counter` and `wrong_counter` as empty lists above your loop. If you set these to the value of the session variables, it will make your logic easier:

```
right_counter = session.counter or 0
wrong_counter = session.wrong_counter or 0

if correct:
   right_counter = int(right_counter) + 1
if not correct:
   wrong_counter = int(wrong_counter) + 1

session.counter = right_counter
session.wrong_counter = wrong_counter
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I  mentioned, I have tried a lot of different things, including some of the solutions in your answer. However, it still displays `None` . I tried to replace the empty lists with `right_counter = session.counter or 0` as you suggested, but it still displays `None`, not `0`

Comment: Debug your session, create a view with `def status():
    return dict(request=request, session=session, response=response)` and then in the template `{{=response.toolbar()}}`